# Two SQL Queries With Some Overlapping Data

Tags: sql

I'm trying to combine two different SQL queries into one table. I've tried various joins and Union but it either duplicates rows or doesn't show all of them.

The first query is

```
Select
HW.DisplayName,
HW.LocationDetails_0B39A057_2BE8_11B2_BBE2_1E03564AA5CA,
HW.Notes_5CFC0E2A_AB82_5830_D4BB_0596CBED1984
FROM MT_Cireson$AssetManagement$HardwareAsset HW
where HardwareAssetStatus_3019ADDF_4F3D_2C55_2024_72C22E11F4CF = '866879DF-8FB6-E521-F0E3-FEF86EE1BC92'
```

This gives all of my hardware assets that have the status I'm looking for.

The second query is:

```
SELECT 
hw.DisplayName,
HW.LocationDetails_0B39A057_2BE8_11B2_BBE2_1E03564AA5CA,
HW.Notes_5CFC0E2A_AB82_5830_D4BB_0596CBED1984,
UB.UPN_7641DFF7_7A20_DC04_FC1C_B6FA8715DA02

FROM MT_Cireson$AssetManagement$HardwareAsset HW
inner join Relationship Rel on HW.BaseManagedEntityId = Rel.SourceEntityId
inner join RelationshipType RT on RT.RelationshipTypeId = Rel.RelationshipTypeId
inner join MT_Microsoft$AD$UserBase UB on UB.BaseManagedEntityId = Rel.TargetEntityId
where RT.RelationshipTypeName = 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasPrimaryUser'
and HardwareAssetStatus_3019ADDF_4F3D_2C55_2024_72C22E11F4CF = '866879DF-8FB6-E521-F0E3-FEF86EE1BC92'
```

This gives all of the hardware assets I'm looking for that have a primary user configured, but doesn't give the assets without a primary user. I'm not sure how to either A: combine the results just putting in NULL as a primary user for records that don't have one, or B: actually query all the assets at one time and include the primary user column.

I didn't write the second query and I'm not sure exactly how it works. I've tried doing union between the queries but that duplicates the rows because the first query already contains all the elements in the second.

Edit: The PrimaryUser comes from the MT_Microsoft$AD$UserBase table. I've tried adding another column to the first and just setting it as null like:

```
null as primaryUser,
```

Comment: What's the `Primary User` column name and on which table is it located?

Comment: The `primary user` comes from `MT_Microsoft$AD$UserBase` through a series of links which all of the inner joins link up.

Answer (score 1):

How about a `LEFT JOIN` to include all records from `HW` that are not in `UB`:

```
SELECT 
  hw.DisplayName,
  HW.LocationDetails_0B39A057_2BE8_11B2_BBE2_1E03564AA5CA,
  HW.Notes_5CFC0E2A_AB82_5830_D4BB_0596CBED1984,
  UB.UPN_7641DFF7_7A20_DC04_FC1C_B6FA8715DA02
FROM
  MT_Cireson$AssetManagement$HardwareAsset HW
INNER JOIN
  Relationship Rel
ON
  HW.BaseManagedEntityId = Rel.SourceEntityId
INNER JOIN
  RelationshipType RT
ON
  RT.RelationshipTypeId = Rel.RelationshipTypeId
LEFT JOIN
  MT_Microsoft$AD$UserBase UB
ON
  UB.BaseManagedEntityId = Rel.TargetEntityId
WHERE
  RT.RelationshipTypeName = 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasPrimaryUser'
  AND HardwareAssetStatus_3019ADDF_4F3D_2C55_2024_72C22E11F4CF = '866879DF-8FB6-E521-F0E3-FEF86EE1BC92'
```

**UPDATE:**

If the `null` primary users is what you want, I would recraft the query like:

```
SELECT 
      hw.DisplayName,
      HW.LocationDetails_0B39A057_2BE8_11B2_BBE2_1E03564AA5CA,
      HW.Notes_5CFC0E2A_AB82_5830_D4BB_0596CBED1984,
      UB.UPN_7641DFF7_7A20_DC04_FC1C_B6FA8715DA02
    FROM
      MT_Cireson$AssetManagement$HardwareAsset HW
    LEFT JOIN
      MT_Microsoft$AD$UserBase UB
    ON
      HW.BaseManagedEntityId = UB.SourceEntityId
    INNER JOIN
      RelationshipType RT
    ON
      RT.RelationshipTypeId = Rel.RelationshipTypeId
    INNER JOIN
      Relationship Rel
    ON
      UB.BaseManagedEntityId = Rel.TargetEntityId
    WHERE
      RT.RelationshipTypeName = 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasPrimaryUser'
      AND HardwareAssetStatus_3019ADDF_4F3D_2C55_2024_72C22E11F4CF = '866879DF-8FB6-E521-F0E3-FEF86EE1BC92'
```

I `LEFT JOIN`'ed `HW` and `UB` tables.

As I said earlier, you'll have to tweak the joins. I would try a `LEFT JOIN` on all tables.

Comment: This seems like it's on the right track. The first query by itself finds 473 and the second finds 310. This query gets 318, with 8 of them having the null Primary User. 

Perhaps it's necessary to use a more inclusive join when drilling down to find the PrimaryUser? I'm still confused on how that connection works.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was just going to post, you'll have to tweak the other joins too.

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra column in your 1st query that's why you have duplicates in your union. I would suggest using CTE, there might be other better efficient solutions out there.

```
;WITH query1
AS 
(
 SELECT col1, col2
 FROM table
), 
query2 AS
(
  SELECT col1, col2
  FROM table
)
SELECT *
FROM cteTable1  
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM cteTable2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM cteTable1 WHERE cteTable1.col1 = cteTable2.col2)
```

Comment: I get an error on the last line when I try this `select query1 where query1.name = query2.name` both instances of query1 have syntax errors.

Comment: @JamesJohnson ops I missed '* FROM', I've edited my answer